# jQuery scrolling menu not animating correctly

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to debug this piece of jQuery code that somebody else wrote, and not having much success.

Basically, it is a drop down menu that has more items than are in view, so there are up and down arrows to scroll the menu. What happens, is that after you scroll down, then mouseout, then mouseover again, the animation repeats, instead of staying at the bottom of the menu.

I know there isn't alot of detail and code here, but its part of a very large application, and was hoping that there was a glaring mistake that jumps right out. Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
//Menu Scroll Up
            jQuery(this).children("div").children(".learn_more_menu_up").mouseover(function(){
                jQuery(this).siblings("ul").stop().animate({scrollTop: "-" + menuFullHeight}, menuScrollDuration);
                jQuery(this).mouseout(function(){
                    jQuery(this).siblings("ul").stop();
                });
            });

//Menu Scroll Down
            jQuery(this).children("div").children(".learn_more_menu_down").mouseover(function(){                    
                jQuery(this).siblings("ul").stop().animate({scrollTop: menuFullHeight}, menuScrollDuration);
                jQuery(this).mouseout(function(){
                    jQuery(this).siblings("ul").stop();
                });
            })
```

Comment: the markup or even a sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

from the given code, every time you mouseover .learn_more_menu_down, the scrollTop will animate, so you should see the animation every time. you need to check for if the menu is at the bottom, if so don't do anything, if not it should only animate from where you are in the menu to the bottom.

if you can link us to the page with the problem or have some sample simplified mark up, it would help